# Creating categories by reading a line of text

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, txt

Good morning,
I am reading several text files which are composed as follows:

```
  PRODUCT_ID               = 
  LABORATORY               = 
  DATE                     = 
  COLOUR                   = 
  FLAGS                    = WORD1 WORD2 WORD3
  CATEGORY                 = 
  COMMENTS                 =
```

My goal is to create a dictionary that categorises my files according to the words that are present in FLAGS. This means that if a file has several FLAGs it would be placed in each category.
I tried to write this code but unfortunately, I cannot separate the interpretation of the words.

```
Flag_groups = {}

for All in file_list:
    file = open(All, 'r', encoding='latin-1')
    file_txt = file.read() #leggo il file
    regex = 'FLAGS\s+=\s+(.+)'  
    searched = re.search(regex, file_txt) 
    if (searched):
        try:
             Flag_groups[searched[1]].append(All)
        except Exception:
             Flag_groups[searched[1]] = [All]
    else:
        try:
             Flag_groups["No_value"].append(All)
        except Exception:
             Flag_groups["No_value"] = [All]
    file.close()
```

For greater clarity I am including a photo of the current result. You can see that when I have several keywords a category is formed

[image]

Comment: You mean, split the "word1 word2 word3" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial solution to your problem. It's unclear (to me) what the purpose of the 'No_value' key is so I've left that out:

```
flag_groups = dict()

file_list = [] # your list of files goes here

for filename in file_list:
    with open(filename, encoding='latin-1') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith('FLAGS'):
                tokens = line.split('=')
                if len(tokens) == 2:
                    for kw in tokens[1].split():
                        flag_groups.setdefault(kw, []).append(filename)
```

**Note:**

You don't really need *re* for this